# Merge fields in user created email templates in django

Tags: python, django, email

So I'm going to have users type up a draft document for email confirmation for a booking application. This draft could look something like this:

`Dear [contactname], 
This is your booking confirmation for your vacation from [startdate] to [enddate] for a total of [numdays] days.
Please click [cancellink] to cancel your booking.`

An email only makes sense in relation to a booking object. Currently I have a method that takes a booking object and a merge string and decides what to do like:

```py
def merge_field(booking, ms):
    if ms == 'contactname':
        return booking.contactsheet.name
    elif ms == 'startdate':
        return str(booking.firstday)
    elif ms == 'enddate':
        return str(booking.lastday)
    elif ms == 'numdays':
        return str((booking.firstday - booking.lastday).days + 1)
    elif ms == 'cancellink':
        return '<a href="http://server.com/cancelbooking/' + str(booking.hashvalue) + '">cancel</a>'
```

This hardcoded approach is pretty ugly. I would much rather prefer to have the users supply a string I could parse and infer some meaning like references into the booking object, some arithmetic and static strings (like in the link). I imagine a model like:

```py
class MergeField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    formula = models.TextField()
```

Then the users could design and test their own merge fields and use them in the email templates. This would make it much easier to maintain. However, I have no idea how I would parse this formula field.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to use the django template system. Have the user enter the message in django template format like:
    Dear {{contactname}}, 
    This is your booking confirmation for your vacation from {{startdate}} to {{enddate}} for a total of {{numdays}} days.
    Please click {{cancellink}} to cancel your booking.

And then use `get_template_from_string` from `django.template.loader` and get a template instance. Than you can render the template by doing template.render(context), Where context is a `Context` instance found in `django.template.context`.
You can read more about django template api in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/ Should be simple from here.

Comment: I like it. I didn't know you could do that. I'm sure it's exactly the way it should be done. Will make this the accepted answer when I get a chance to work on it.

Comment: Ok. Good luck. Leave me a comment if you need any more advice.

Comment: It looks like they suggest Template() instead of get_template_from_string() but it's basically the same it seems. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/